# Error while making Java window Service using Tanuki Software

Tags: java, windows-services, wrapper, java-service-wrapper

I am using Tanuki Software to make a window service for java.  Here is my config file.

```
#encoding=UTF-8
# Configuration files must begin with a line specifying the encoding
#  of the the file.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper License Properties (Ignored by Community Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Professional and Standard Editions of the Wrapper require a valid
#  License Key to start.  Licenses can be purchased or a trial license
#  requested on the following pages:
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/purchase
# http://wrapper.tanukisoftware.com/trial

# Include file problems can be debugged by removing the first '#'
#  from the following line:
##include.debug

# The Wrapper will look for either of the following optional files for a
#  valid License Key.  License Key properties can optionally be included
#  directly in this configuration file.
#include ../conf/wrapper-license.conf
#include ../conf/wrapper-license-%WRAPPER_HOST_NAME%.conf

# The following property will output information about which License Key(s)
#  are being found, and can aid in resolving any licensing problems.
#wrapper.license.debug=TRUE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Localization
#********************************************************************
# Specify the locale which the Wrapper should use.  By default the system
#  locale is used.
#wrapper.lang=en_US # en_US or ja_JP

# Specify the location of the Wrapper's language resources.  If these are
#  missing, the Wrapper will default to the en_US locale.
wrapper.lang.folder=../lang

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Java Properties
#********************************************************************
# Java Application
#  Locate the java binary on the system PATH:
wrapper.java.command=java
#  Specify a specific java binary:
#set.JAVA_HOME=/java/path
#wrapper.java.command=%JAVA_HOME%/bin/java

# Tell the Wrapper to log the full generated Java command line.
#wrapper.java.command.loglevel=INFO

# Java Main class.  This class must implement the WrapperListener interface
#  or guarantee that the WrapperManager class is initialized.  Helper
#  classes are provided to do this for you.  See the Integration section
#  of the documentation for details.
wrapper.java.mainclass=org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp

# Java Classpath (include wrapper.jar)  Add class path elements as
#  needed starting from 1
wrapper.java.classpath.1=sendmaill.SendMail
wrapper.java.classpath.2=../lib/wrapper.jar
wrapper.java.classpath.3=sendmaill.jar

# Java Library Path (location of Wrapper.DLL or libwrapper.so)
wrapper.java.library.path.1=../lib

# Java Bits.  On applicable platforms, tells the JVM to run in 32 or 64-bit mode.
wrapper.java.additional.auto_bits=TRUE

# Java Additional Parameters
wrapper.java.additional.1=

# Initial Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.initmemory=3

# Maximum Java Heap Size (in MB)
#wrapper.java.maxmemory=64

# Application parameters.  Add parameters as needed starting from 1
#wrapper.app.parameter.1=

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Logging Properties
#********************************************************************
# Enables Debug output from the Wrapper.
# wrapper.debug=TRUE

# Format of output for the console.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.console.format=PM

# Log Level for console output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.console.loglevel=INFO

# Log file to use for wrapper output logging.
wrapper.logfile=../logs/wrapper.log

# Format of output for the log file.  (See docs for formats)
wrapper.logfile.format=LPTM

# Log Level for log file output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.logfile.loglevel=INFO

# Maximum size that the log file will be allowed to grow to before
#  the log is rolled. Size is specified in bytes.  The default value
#  of 0, disables log rolling.  May abbreviate with the 'k' (kb) or
#  'm' (mb) suffix.  For example: 10m = 10 megabytes.
wrapper.logfile.maxsize=0

# Maximum number of rolled log files which will be allowed before old
#  files are deleted.  The default value of 0 implies no limit.
wrapper.logfile.maxfiles=0

# Log Level for sys/event log output.  (See docs for log levels)
wrapper.syslog.loglevel=NONE

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper General Properties
#********************************************************************
# Allow for the use of non-contiguous numbered properties
wrapper.ignore_sequence_gaps=TRUE

# Do not start if the pid file already exists.
wrapper.pidfile.strict=TRUE

# Title to use when running as a console
wrapper.console.title=Test Wrapper Sample Application

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper JVM Checks
#********************************************************************
# Detect DeadLocked Threads in the JVM. (Requires Standard Edition)
wrapper.check.deadlock=TRUE
wrapper.check.deadlock.interval=10
wrapper.check.deadlock.action=RESTART
wrapper.check.deadlock.output=FULL

# Out Of Memory detection.
# (Ignore output from dumping the configuration to the console.  This is only needed by the TestWrapper sample application.)
wrapper.filter.trigger.999=wrapper.filter.trigger.*java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.999=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.999=NONE
#  Ignore -verbose:class output to avoid false positives.
wrapper.filter.trigger.1000=[Loaded java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
wrapper.filter.action.1000=NONE
# (Simple match)
wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
# (Only match text in stack traces if -XX:+PrintClassHistogram is being used.)
#wrapper.filter.trigger.1001=Exception in thread "*" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
#wrapper.filter.allow_wildcards.1001=TRUE
wrapper.filter.action.1001=RESTART
wrapper.filter.message.1001=The JVM has run out of memory.

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Email Notifications. (Requires Professional Edition)
#********************************************************************
# Common Event Email settings.
#wrapper.event.default.email.debug=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.host=<SMTP_Host>
#wrapper.event.default.email.smtp.port=25
#wrapper.event.default.email.subject=[%WRAPPER_HOSTNAME%:%WRAPPER_NAME%:%WRAPPER_EVENT_NAME%] Event Notification
#wrapper.event.default.email.sender=<Sender email>
#wrapper.event.default.email.recipient=<Recipient email>

# Configure the log attached to event emails.
#wrapper.event.default.email.attach_log=TRUE
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.lines=50
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.format=LPTM
#wrapper.event.default.email.maillog.loglevel=INFO

# Enable specific event emails.
#wrapper.event.wrapper_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_prelaunch.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_start.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_started.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_deadlock.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stop.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_stopped.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_failed_invocation.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_max_failed_invocations.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_kill.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_killed.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.jvm_unexpected_exit.email=TRUE
#wrapper.event.wrapper_stop.email=TRUE

# Specify custom mail content
wrapper.event.jvm_restart.email.body=The JVM was restarted.\n\nPlease check on its status.\n

#********************************************************************
# Wrapper Windows NT/2000/XP Service Properties
#********************************************************************
# WARNING - Do not modify any of these properties when an application
#  using this configuration file has been installed as a service.
#  Please uninstall the service before modifying this section.  The
#  service can then be reinstalled.

# Name of the service
wrapper.name=SendMail

# Display name of the service
wrapper.displayname=SendMail

# Description of the service
wrapper.description=Send Mail

# Service dependencies.  Add dependencies as needed starting from 1
wrapper.ntservice.dependency.1=

# Mode in which the service is installed.  AUTO_START, DELAY_START or DEMAND_START
wrapper.ntservice.starttype=AUTO_START

# Allow the service to interact with the desktop.
wrapper.ntservice.interactive=false
```

SendMail is the name of my class while sendmaill is my jar file.
When i will run StartTestWrapper-NT.bat file its give an error. I can see my service in the window services but when i click it to start it through an error.
Here is the log file tanuki software.

```
NOTICE | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:03 | --------------------------------------------------------------------
NOTICE | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:03 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:03 | 
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:03 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 | 
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 1    | 2013/12/31 18:13:04 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:06 | JVM exited while loading the application.
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:08 | Waiting to start...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | 
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 2    | 2013/12/31 18:13:10 |                   application.
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:13 | Waiting to start...
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:12 | JVM exited while loading the application.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:18 | Waiting to start...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | 
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | 
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 3    | 2013/12/31 18:13:17 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:19 | JVM exited while loading the application.
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:23 | Waiting to start...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:23 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 | 
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 | 
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 4    | 2013/12/31 18:13:24 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:26 | JVM exited while loading the application.
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:28 | Waiting to start...
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | Launching a JVM...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | WrapperManager: Initializing...
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | WrapperSimpleApp Usage:
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 |   java org.tanukisoftware.wrapper.WrapperSimpleApp {app_class{/app_method}} [app_arguments]
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | 
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 | Where:
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 |   app_class:      The fully qualified class name of the application to run.
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 |   app_arguments:  The arguments that would normally be passed to the
INFO   | jvm 5    | 2013/12/31 18:13:30 |                   application.
ERROR  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:32 | JVM exited while loading the application.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:33 | There were 5 failed launches in a row, each lasting less than 300 seconds.  Giving up.
FATAL  | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:33 |   There may be a configuration problem: please check the logs.
STATUS | wrapper  | 2013/12/31 18:13:33 | <-- Wrapper Stopped
INFO   | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:33 | Waiting to start...
ERROR  | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:34 | The SendMail service was launched, but failed to start.
ERROR  | wrapperm | 2013/12/31 18:13:34 | Please check the log file more information: F:\Java Work\wrapper-windows-x86-64-3.5.22-st\wrapper-windows-x86-64-3.5.22-st\logs\wrapper.log
```

Any Help is very appreciable.

Answer (score 1):

Malik,
The problem is that the WrapperSimpleApp class expects a class name as an argument.  You are not currently passing any arguments.  Please try adding the following:

```
wrapper.app.parameter.1=SendMail
```

This assumes that the full class name of your main class is "SendMail" as you said.

Cheers,
Leif